# ANTLR grammar is giving unexpected results

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

This is very simple.  I'm in the process of learning ANTLR4 by inventing a grammar that can recognize a single word.  But why isn't it matching my name?  It's printing out `[ ]`.

I am using Antlr 4 with C# 4.5.

#### MyFirstGrammar.g4:

```
grammar MyFirstGrammar;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

compileUnit
    :   ID
    ;


/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

ID  :   [A-Za-z]+ ;

WS  :   ' ' -> skip ;
```

#### Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var stream = new AntlrInputStream("amy");
        var lexer = new Grammars.MyFirstGrammarLexer(stream);
        var tokens= new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        var parser = new Grammars.MyFirstGrammarParser(tokens);
        var root = parser.compileUnit();
        Debug.WriteLine(root);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... **it works**, except the `RuleContext` class doesn't define `ToString` in [the way you expect](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/blob/b26ce4d0321cba3661f2f4b316cf97e479ef70fc/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4.Runtime/RuleContext.cs#L317).
The ANTLR-generated `CompileUnitContext` class extends `ParserRuleContext`, which extends `RuleContext`.

Try this:

```
Debug.WriteLine(root.ToStringTree(parser));
```

It will print the [parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree):

```
(compileUnit amy)
```

Or perhaps you're just looking for this:

```
Debug.WriteLine(root.GetText());
```

Which will print `amy` as you expect. :)

Comment: ahhhhhh!  I'm not going crazy after all!  Thanks!